# How do simplify megamenu this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to simplify this code but can't think which way  to do it, any ideas? Its effectively a mega mega

```
$(function() {
    $('#globalnavigation').find("a").bind({
        click: function() {
            if (".submenu:hidden") {
                $(".submenu").css("display", "block");
            }
            if ($('a[href$="#a-menu"]')) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("#services-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#innovations-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#insights-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#professionals-menu").fadeIn(750);
            }
            if ($('a[href$="#b-menu"]')) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("#professionals-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#innovations-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#insights-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#services-menu").fadeIn(750);
            }
            if ($('a[href$="#c-menu"]')) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("#services-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#innovations-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#professionals-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#insights-menu").fadeIn(750);
            }
            if ($('a[href$="#d-menu"]')) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("#services-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#professionals-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#insights-menu").css("display", "none");
                $("#innovations-menu").fadeIn(750);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the html? A live example?

Comment: Where's your HTML? Also, for something this large, consider using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to share the code; it makes it easier for others to visalize what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ivodesign you can also consider indenting your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
.submenu-content
{
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="globalnavigation">         
    <ul>
        <li><a id="menu-item-a" href="#professionals-menu">Professionals</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu-item-b" href="#services-menu">Services</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu-item-c" href="#insights-menu">Insights</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu-item-d" href="#innovation-menu">Innovation</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="submenu" style="display: block;">
    ...
    <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-a">
    <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-b">
    <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-c">
    <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-d">
    ...
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('#globalnavigation').find("a").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");        
        $('.submenu').show();
        $('.submenu-content').hide();

        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('menu-item-', '');
        $('#submenu-content-' + id).fadeIn(750);
    });
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, how do i make my code more efficent? In enligh i guess you would say... For Every link in the global menu i clicked, show the related submenu. But it another submenu is already displayed hide it first. Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the code.  If you have multiple submenus, then you can similarly hide all first (based on class name) and then show whichever you want.  This is pseudo code, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Ok that response was ridiculously fast! and almost exactly what i wanted, Thank you Kon, you're a genius!

Comment: Haha..  we aim to please.  :)

Comment: One thing i'm struggling with is removing the active class when you click on another #globalnavigation link. Currently whats happening is every time you click on a link the previous #globalnavigation links are still highlighted. How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

to start with you can consolidate your css calls

```
$("#a-menu,#b-menu,#c-menu").css("display", "none");
$("#d-menu").fadeIn(750);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
formatMenus('a[href$="#a-menu"]');
formatMenus('a[href$="#b-menu"]');

function formatMenus(selector)
{            
    if ($(selector)) 
    {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#services-menu").css("display", "none");
        $("#innovations-menu").css("display", "none");
        $("#insights-menu").css("display", "none");
        $("#professionals-menu").fadeIn(750);
    }
}
```